# Why should I use Object instead of DataSet as the return type of my WCF Method?

Tags: object, dataset, return-type, wcf

I heard some people saying Returning DataSet as a return type of your WCF method is not a good practice. What are the problems if I use DataSet as return type of my method? What are the advantages of using a List of Objects instead of DataSet?

Sending a List of State object (ID,StateCode,StateName) or DataSet?

I was told by a friend that having DataSet as return type has an advantage. If tomorrow client is saying (assume I published the service and some outside customers are using that), my client is saying I want some more information about the object (ex: Need a "Notes" field about the State), I don't need to change the signature of my contract. I just add the notes to my dataset. This will not break any existing contract.

I heard that there is performance issues if I use dataset? How big is that impact? What are the other issues? Why people write DataSet is evil?

Trying to evolve as a good developer by switching to good coding practices.

Comment: I believe this site is a great source to learn things. I am surprised to see this question is closed. I asked a question to know which coding practice i should use. I believe the whole idea of this website is to share info and guide people to be better programmers.I really wish instead of closing this question, If some body could give proper answer.  I really don't understand why this question cant have answers of type "facts" or "specific experitse" !!! I was looking for "specific expertise to correct myself. I am newbie!

Answer (score 1):

Dataset leaks platform details. Dataset is microsoft implementation and when you expose that over a service, then clients who use the same platform as the data being exposed can only consume the service. That basically makes your service consumable only on microsoft platforms which against the whole point of a service. Other thing is that dataset when serialized contains huge amoount of unrelated data for a client, like datarelations etc..

And regarding your "Notes" example, Boundaries are supposed to be explicit when you define a service. So the outside world has to know what is the type of data that you are sending across the service and its structure.